# Substitute default value for missing element

Tags: xml, xsd

An excerpt of my schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
        <xs:element name="baz" type="bax_type" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:simpleType name="baz_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
        <xs:enumeration value="none"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="wombat"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

That is, I've got an an element of an enumeration type which can be missing. Is it possible to get the following behavior:

1. On the following XML it gives the default value of `none` instead of `null` - i.e. `foo.getBaz() == BazType.NONE`

This XML should be valid for backward compatibility.

```
    <foo>
        <bar>1</bar>
    </foo>
```

1. This one parses correctly:

   ```
   <foo>
       <bar>1</bar>
       <baz>wombat</baz>
   </foo>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Choice Indicator , please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp)